# Confusion about angular $digest cycle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a directive that will allow you to style a "dropdown" anyway you like. Basically what I'm doing is hiding the actual select element and providing a div with a ul that will have all the options as list items. Eventually it will dynamically control the select element so you can use the fake dropdown and retain the functionality of the select element. The problem I'm running into is that I'm using $scope.$watch to watch the children of the select element. The options elements. So anytime they are updated the ul will also be updated automatically. I'm running into what I think is a weird $digest issue. I've created a JSBIN [here](http://jsbin.com/heqay/4/). If you click add once nothing happens. If you click it again two li's are added to the ul. If you continue this patter you'll notice that every second click the li's are updated. I created a second JSBIN [here](http://jsbin.com/gexuwe/1/) and used $timeout. In the $timeout I call $digest and the ul is updated correctly. I'm very confused as to why this is happening. I thought ng-click would trigger a $digest, which is seems to do, but only every second click. That is what is truly confusing to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The goal is for this directive to be a module indepent of other code (as modules should be). So I can't depend on someone running a $digest in their controller. I'm also at a lose as to why it's happening every second click and really really need to know why.

**UPDATE:**

I've found a work around for what I want to do. My issue now is that for some reason when I trigger the change event on the select element using triggerHandler it get a $apply already in progress error. I can't, for the life of me, figure out why. [Here](http://jsbin.com/yavane/1/) is the new JSBIN.

Comment: approach is all wrong. Don't think of DOM elements, think of the data model. Angular takes care of creating the elements for you. Watch the model, not the elements it creates

Comment: In your current state, you don't even need to use `$watch` at all

Comment: @charlietfl could you elaborate more. what model would i watch? since this is a module i won't know what their model is called. the goal is to be able to create the li's with no additional work from the developer if that makes sense.

Comment: pass the data into scope of directive, angular will watch it automatically and add/remove dom elements based on the data array changes

Comment: @charlietfl that was the original plan, but there is no way for me to tell what they are using for the html of the option. in other words, given an array of objects like [{name: "John", age: 30}, {name: "Jane", age: 31}], how would i know what they the model to be. They may be using {{item.name}} or {{item.age}}. Since i can't know what they are using i have to base it off the the rendered dropdown list which has the rendered html.

Comment: so you pass the properties needed into directive